# How to convert a list to a Dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I scraped a table from Wikipedia, using Pandas and BeautifulSoup, I obtained a list. I want to convert it into a Dataframe, but when I use the pd.DataFrame() function, the result is not as expected. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
print(df[0].to_json(orient='records'))
```

Everything goes right until this point, but after that when I try the following code

```
neigh = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

It just returns one row and one column output.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a pandas DataFrame encapsulated in a list. You just have to take the first element:

```py
neigh = df[0]
print(neigh)
```

```
    Postcode           Borough          Neighbourhood
0        M1A      Not assigned           Not assigned
1        M2A      Not assigned           Not assigned
2        M3A        North York              Parkwoods
3        M4A        North York       Victoria Village
4        M5A  Downtown Toronto           Harbourfront
..       ...               ...                    ...
282      M8Z         Etobicoke              Mimico NW
283      M8Z         Etobicoke     The Queensway West
284      M8Z         Etobicoke  Royal York South West
285      M8Z         Etobicoke         South of Bloor
286      M9Z      Not assigned           Not assigned

[287 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read the tables from the url directly using the `pandas`, `read_html` function

```
>>> url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M"
>>> tables = pd.read_html(url)
>>> len(tables)
3
>>> tables[0]
    Postcode           Borough          Neighbourhood
0        M1A      Not assigned           Not assigned
1        M2A      Not assigned           Not assigned
2        M3A        North York              Parkwoods
3        M4A        North York       Victoria Village
4        M5A  Downtown Toronto           Harbourfront
..       ...               ...                    ...
282      M8Z         Etobicoke              Mimico NW
283      M8Z         Etobicoke     The Queensway West
284      M8Z         Etobicoke  Royal York South West
285      M8Z         Etobicoke         South of Bloor
286      M9Z      Not assigned           Not assigned

[287 rows x 3 columns]
>>> type(tables[0])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

`read_html` will read all the `table` tags from the url and return a list of `dataframes`

Answer (score 1):

You already have dataframe in the df

```
print(df[0])
```